# How does separation of duties work between the kinds of workers described below?

Tags: security

I'm trying to understand how separation of duties works between various job functions as a security measure. For starters, there are computer (hardware) operations, applications programs, and systems programs.

From what I understand, computer operators are supposed to be confined to hardware and hard data. They are not supposed to have anything to do with systems programming or applications programming, because of potential conflicts of interest. I follow this so far.

Likewise, the access of applications programmers are supposed to be limited to applications programs. They are not supposed to have anything to do with the systems programs that control their programs, or with the hard data or hardware. Again, this seems to follow.

The "symmetry" is broken with systems programmers. They are supposed to work with systems, and understandably, are not supposed to have access to applications programs. But my understanding is that they are allowed to have access to the hard data and hardware, when the other two types of personnel aren't allowed outside their areas. Why might this be?

I'm also confused about the roles of two more agents, systems and administrators and systems analysts. Maybe the problem is that I'm getting hung up on the job titles.

Systems administrators are "keepers of the seal" such as providing access abd passwords to the systems. Yet, they are not supposed to have access to the systems, only to applications. Is their function actually an "applications" function, despite their job titles?

Ditto for systems analysts, who oversee and work with applications programmers, and in this regard, are "applications" people who have access to applications. But they're not supposed to have access to systems, despite their job titles.

**Clarification:** In answer to a comment, the question can be restated as follows (in two parts). 1) Why are systems programmers allowed to go outside of systems, (to hardware) when applications programmers and hardware people are expected to stick to issues connected with their departments? 2) why do systems administrators and systems analysts appear have the same scope as "applications" programmers when the term "systems" is in their job titles?

Comment: What is the question? You have a lot of categories. Might be better to look at how separation of duties works between any two categories first. Narrow the question.

Comment: @joshp: The question is twofold: Why are systems programmers allowed to go outside of systems, (to hardware) when applications programmers and hardware people are expected to stick to issues connected with their name. 2) why do systems administrators and systems analysts have the same limits as  "applications" programmers when the term "systems" is in their job titles.

Answer (score 0):

First, your idea of what job titles mean probably doesn't match mine.  Each organization may mean a different thing by a job title.

Second, "symmetry" isn't important.  It's all about levels of trust.

An application is run by an ordinary user, so it shouldn't be allowed to disrupt the system.  Following on from that, application programmers also have no need to access "dangerous" functions in the system.

Systems software is the underlying stuff that provides important functions behind the scenes.  It's therefore inevitable that bad systems software could harm the system as a whole.  So the people who write systems software must be trusted (both in the sense that they are experienced enough not to do anything stupid, and that they are honest enough not to do anything malicious).  Given that, there is no point in preventing systems programmers from working at the application level if they need to (for instance, I could write a printer driver, then write an application to tell the users whether or not a printer is working correctly).

The system administrator is God.  They can do anything they like.  Obviously, they need to be trustworthy.

Analysts analyze.  Their job is to tell other people what needs to be done.  They don't actually require access to anything, beyond what a normal user would have.